# Changing ubuntu hostname has no effect

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, hostname

I am new to ubuntu and I am trying to change hostname of my ubuntu server 18.04.2 LTS. I've already changed /etc/hostname and /etc/hosts and rebooted. But it didn't work.

My files:
/etc/hostname:

> ubuntu-s2

/etc/hosts:

> 127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   ubuntu-s2
>
> ::1             localhost6.localdomain6 localhost6
>
> ::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
>
> fe00::0 ip6-localnet
>
> ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
>
> ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
> ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

Is the only way to do it to change preserve hostname to true in /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing one thing:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname ubuntu-s2
```

After that, reboot. Your hostname will then be `ubuntu-s2`